# Extract image from img style="background:url('path') but not from src

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, html-parsing

How can i extract the background image given using style attribute in image tag.

In the above tag i want to extract the image from style attribute but not from src. I want the image to be extracted but not the path of the image.

Comment: " I want the image to be extracted but not the path of the image", what do you mean by the image, the image itself??

Comment: The image is not  showing even when i'm giving full path extracted from background url.

Comment: The image tag looks like this, <img src="..//contactdeatils?data=123123"/> How to get the full path. I came to know that because of this only i'm not able to see image.when i opened the file in browser , the path is taking C:/Users/Madhusudhan.M/Desktop/. Url is redirecting to local system but not the path on server.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var imageUrl = document.getElementById('myImage').style.background.image.url;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not getting how to use imageUrl once all the images are extracted into imageUrl variable. In the above answer Duane said we can use HtmlNode in htmlagilitypack but i'm facing problem in placing the images in output file with text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and:

```
var images = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("style") && d.Attributes["style"].Value.Contains("background:url")).ToList();
```

Which will return a list of type `HtmlAgilityPack<HtmlNode>` which holds all of your images, you can then enumerate over them get the values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How to display the images in HtmlNode. How can i include these images in the output string. I'm extracting both images and text from web page.

Comment: I guess you could use `string.Substring` and get the index of the first occurance of `background:url` and then read all text after that up until the ending `)`

Comment: Can you please show me a sample code how to use this.
Below is the code i have used till now to extract the content. 
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();document.LoadHtml(html);var images = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("style") && d.Attributes["style"].Value.Contains("background:url")).ToList();
string target = "";HtmlNodeCollection col = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id=\"resultsTable\"]"); foreach (HtmlNode link in col)
            {
                target += link.InnerHtml;
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any complex html parsing [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good solution.

However if this is all you want to do, a simple regex would do the trick.

If you have set the image using the css tags, image or background-image, you can search for the url and extract the full path.

This very simple regex will do that.

```
url\(.*?\)
```

Extracting only the image path from the full path should be trivial after that.

Answer (score -1):

you could also use simple regex with this problem after xpathing your way using **HTML Agility Pack**

```
style=background:url\('(?<bgpath>.*)'\)
```

**here's a sample code**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string innerHTML = "<img style=\"background:url('images/logo.jpg')\" />";

    string regex = @"style=""background:url\('(?<bgpath>.*)'\)\""";
    RegexOptions options = ((RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline) | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Regex reg = new Regex(regex, options);
    if (reg.IsMatch(innerHTML))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(innerHTML).Groups["bgpath"].Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```